# MySQL SELECT only rows where tbl_col equal to this and that

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am struggling a bit with my SQL query.

This is the query i have now, and it works as is, but i want to add some more to it.

In the mysql table, there is a column that is named "type". I want to filter the rows and get the rows with the string "sms" or the string "email" from column "type".

```
$query = "
 SELECT id_card
     , date_sent
     , status
     , recipient
     , type 
  FROM dc_log 
 WHERE secretcode=?
   AND date_sent BETWEEN ? AND ?
";
```

How do i add this to my query without messing everything up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add: AND type IN ('sms','email')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this condition in the end before the double quotes

```
 AND type IN ('sms','email')
```

**[Resource](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx)**

Comment: Silly me, i tried the same earlier today, but forgot "IN". Your condition work like a charm! Thank you! :)

Comment: @phingoc Mark the answer as a solution in this case.